# How do I replace Root Drive on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, grub2, grub, root-filesystem

How do I replace the root drive on Debian? What is a comprehensive set of steps starting from old drive with a new empty drive ready to go to the new drive with a fully bootable install with grub and everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following makes some assumptions:

- All commands ran as root when possible
- You want an ext4 files system
- You are loosely familiar on a basic level with all commands run
- You are NOT booting from a RAID device

So here we go.

1. Physically install new disk into computer and connect to available port leaving old disk in existing position.
2. Boot computer into old OS.
3. Prepare and mount new disk; first identify new disk

> fdisk -l

4. Partition new disk

> fdisk /dev/(newdisk)
>
> ```
> Make partition primary partition with type "83" file system type.
> ```

5. Create filesystem

> mkfs.ext4 /dev/(newpartition)

6. Mount new filesystem

> mkdir /mnt/(newpartitionmountpoint)
>
> mount /dev/(newpartition) /mnt/(newpartitionmountpoint)

7. Copy disk:

> /sbin/init 1 (drop to single user mode)
>
> rsync -avxHAX / /mnt/(newpartitionmountpoint)
>
> startx

8. Update FSTAB on newdisk

> blkid (note UUID of new partition)
>
> (editor of choice) /mnt/(newpartitionmountpoint)/etc/fstab
>
> ```
>     Replace existing UUID of / in FSTAB to new disk UUID
> ```

9. Configure grub and install to new disk boot loader:

> grub-mkconfig
>
> update-grub
>
> grub-install /dev/(newdisk)

10. Copy grub.cfg from old disk to new

> cp -ax /boot/grub/grub.cfg /mnt/(newpartitionmountpoint)/boot/grub/grub.cfg

11. Open grub.cfg on new disk and replace all UUIDs with new disk

> (editor of choice) /mnt/(newpartitionmountpoint)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
>
> Replace all old UUIDs with the UUID of the new disk

12. Shut down computer

> Shutdown

13. Physically move the new drive to the 1st drive location and remove old drive

    14.Start computer and grub should present:

> error: no such device: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> GRUB rescue>

15. Manually boot new OS from grub; first identify the drive and partition of the boot files

> ls [to identify your drive and partition options]
>
> ls (hdx,p)/ [to identify which partition has the /boot folder]

16. Then, you can load the boot menu manually from the drive and partition you found above.  Typically this would be (hd0,msdos1).

> set prefix="(hdx,p)/boot/grub"
>
> set root="(hdx,p)"
>
> insmod normal
>
> normal

17. Login to OS on new drive
18. Configure grub again

> fdisk -l (note dev of newdisk)
>
> grub-mkconfig
>
> update-grub
>
> grub-install /dev/newdisk

And that should be it!